# Passing list of items from Controller/Model to a variable in javascript - autocomplete

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a method in a NamesModel which fetches all the names and returns a list of names:

```
public static List<NamesModel> GetAllNames()
{
    List<NamesModel> names = new List<NamesModel>();

    // 
    // code to fetch records
    //

    return names;
}
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   NamesModel model = new NamesModel();
   model.GetAllNames();

   return View(model);
}
```

In the view, I've got a textbox:

```
@Html.TextBox("search-name")
```

Now in my javascript, I want to fetch all names into a variable either from a model (from method) or from controller, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {

     var names = ...........
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#search-name').autocomplete({
               source: names
          });
     });
 });
</script>
```

If I use hardcoding then it works but I want to use the names stored in the db. Is it possible?

hardcoding example:

```
var names = ["abc", "xyz"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to my problem is in this blog: http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/jquery-autocomplete-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ajax and Json for this

For your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllNames()
{
   List<NamesModel> names = new List<NamesModel>();

   // 
   // code to fetch records
   //

   return Json(names);
}
```

Or for debugging so you can view the json in browser:

```
public JsonResult GetAllNames()
{
   List<NamesModel> names = new List<NamesModel>();

   // 
   // code to fetch records
   //

   var result = Json(names);
   result .JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
   return result ;
}
```

(note this is actually jquery but since you use document.ready you've allready included jquery)

in your javascript make a call to the method above:

```
$.getJSON(@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/GetAllNames/"), function (result) {
         var ListWithNames = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "source" options property can be a string wich points to the URL which return json data (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)